# Puppet : stop a service if a filesystem is not mounted on boot

Tags: puppet

What is best way to write puppet code - "stop crond if /filesystem is not mounted" (filesystem mount is taken care by Redhat Cluter)"

Comment: I think you'd be better off adjusting your cron jobs to check if the file system is mounted before attempting to do anything rather than killing cron (which does other tasks not related to your mount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` is probably easiest way to deal with this :

```
exec { "stop_crond" :
   command => "service crond stop",
   path => "/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin",
   unless => 'mount | grep -oq "/filesystem"',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest writing a [custom fact](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/fact_overview.html) to check your filesystem mount. Using that variable, you can declare your `crond` service either `stopped`, or `running`, etc.

Alternatively, you could do something like an `exec` to stop `crond`, using `onlyif` to check the mount. For example, grepping for the name of your filesystem in the output of `mount`.

The custom fact approach is cleaner, more reliable, and better style; if you're in a rush, the `exec` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me.

```
exec { "stop_crond":
command => "service crond stop",
path    => "/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin",
unless  => '/bin/cat /proc/mounts | /bin/grep -q \' /mnt \'';
}
```